# Android:Reading XML File containing HTML code

Tags: android, html, rss, cdata, rss-reader

**Hi everybody;
I have an xml file "feed.xml" with a form like that:**

```
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<item>
<cache>0</cache>
<id>v_article_16337.html</id>
<article_id>16337</article_id>
<type>article</type>
<img>
http://website.com/main/image.jpg
</img>
<filename>
http://website.com/other/image.jpg
</filename>
<origine_filename>
http://website.com/image.jpg
</origine_filename>
<title>
<![CDATA[
Here plain text
]]>
</title>

<datePub>
<![CDATA[ 28.03.2013 | 08h00 | ]]>
</datePub>
<nbrComment>0</nbrComment>
<lastComment>
<![CDATA[ ]]>
</lastComment>
<theSameCategorie>
<![CDATA[
Here HTML Code
]]>
</theSameCategorie>
<description>
<![CDATA[
Here plain text
]]>
</description>
<content>
<![CDATA[

Here html code
]]>
</content>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

**I need how to parse all these information and saving it in local file so that i can watch it later if no internet connection is available,i found that if CDATA tag,the value will be ignored !
Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

You either have to loop through all children (no matter how many) and concatenate the value of each to get the full result, or if it's not important for you to differentiate between plain text and text inside CDATA, then set the coalescing property on the document builder factory first:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
docFactory.setCoalescing(true);
```